# Synchronize UIView CALayer draw with UIScrollView

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uikit, calayer, cashapelayer

I'm trying to make an application that will draw on top of a pdf. It is required that graphic shapes be tied to a specific position on the page.

To solve the problem, I use PDFView and CALayer, listen to the events of the internal UIScrollView scrollViewDidScroll and scrollViewDidZoom to redraw the CALayer

I found two ways to draw:

1. Use the "path" property of CAShapeLayer ([example 1](https://www.youtube.com/shorts/ZYcw2Mu2pBQ))
2. Override the "draw" method of CALayer ([example 2](https://www.youtube.com/shorts/bHBB_UFwF24))

I noticed that in the second case the figure lags noticeably behind the pdf document when scrolling or zooming.

The question is, what is so “magic” done in the “path” method that leads to instant redrawing? Is it possible to modify the “draw” method so that it works as synchronously as “path”? And how stable will the "path" method work in the future?

Check out the project to compile&run: https://github.com/alzhuravlev/DrawTest.git

Sample code:

```swift
class AnnotationsLayer: CAShapeLayer {
...

  override func draw(in ctx: CGContext) {
        guard let backgroundView else { return }

        ctx.setFillColor(UIColor.red.withAlphaComponent(0.4).cgColor)
        ctx.setStrokeColor(UIColor.green.withAlphaComponent(1.0).cgColor)
        ctx.setLineWidth(10)

        backgroundView.pages.forEach { page in
            let p1 = backgroundView.convert(point: CGPoint(x: page.size.width/3, y: page.size.height/3), from: page.index)
            let p2 = backgroundView.convert(point: CGPoint(x: page.size.width/3*2, y: page.size.height/3*2), from: page.index)

            ctx.move(to: CGPoint(x: p1.x, y: p1.y))
            ctx.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: p2.x, y: p1.y))
            ctx.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: p2.x, y: p2.y))
            ctx.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: p1.x, y: p2.y))
            ctx.closePath()
        }


        ctx.drawPath(using: CGPathDrawingMode.fillStroke)
    }

    func rebuildShapes() {
        
        // false - example 1
        // true - example 2
        if (false) { 
            setNeedsDisplay()
        } else {
            
            guard let backgroundView else { return }
            
            let p = UIBezierPath()
            
            fillColor = UIColor.red.withAlphaComponent(0.4).cgColor
            
            strokeColor = UIColor.green.withAlphaComponent(1.0).cgColor
            lineWidth = 10
            
            backgroundView.pages.forEach { page in
                let p1 = backgroundView.convert(point: CGPoint(x: page.size.width/3, y: page.size.height/3), from: page.index)
                let p2 = backgroundView.convert(point: CGPoint(x: page.size.width/3*2, y: page.size.height/3*2), from: page.index)
                
                p.move(to: CGPoint(x: p1.x, y: p1.y))
                p.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: p2.x, y: p1.y))
                p.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: p2.x, y: p2.y))
                p.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: p1.x, y: p2.y))
                p.close()
            }
            
            path = p.cgPath
        }
    }
...
```

Comment: `CAShapeLayer` with path is **highly optimized** by Apple engineers. It's difficult to know where your code is slowing things down without being able to run it. If you really want to override draw, post a [mre] that we can run.

Comment: Here it is https://github.com/alzhuravlev/DrawTest.git

Comment: I took a look at your repo... tough to tell without spending a bunch of time with instruments, but my guess is that overriding `draw(in ctx: CGContext)` in the `CAShapeLayer` ends up being much less efficient than using `.path`. Perhaps worth noting... you could simplify this by overriding `draw(_ rect: CGRect)` in `AnnotationsView` instead of adding the layer. You also get clear, sharp edges (instead of the fuzzy edges in your current implementation).

Comment: For reference: https://i.stack.imgur.com/U7kDd.png

Comment: I have a hypothesis that the drawing in the CALayer.draw method lags behind because the drawing occurs in a buffer which is transferred to the screen delayed in the next frames, i.e. the coordinates that we collected are already outdated in relation to the state of the scrollView. And by setting the shape to the CAShapeLayer.path property, this buffer is reset immediately

Comment: Unless you have a **specific reason** to handle the shape layer drawing, I wouldn't put any more time into investigating it. Better to use what you know works. Personally, I'd use a `UIView` and override `draw(_ rect: CGRect)` instead of adding a shape layer.

Comment: @DonMag your advice to use UIView.draw is quite good, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on OP's comments, here is what I would use instead of overriding `draw(in ctx: CGContext)` in a `CAShapeLayer`:

```
class AnnotationsView: UIView {
    var backgroundView: BackgroundView? {
        didSet {
            print("did set background view")
        }
    }
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    func commonInit() {
        backgroundColor = .clear
    }
    func rebuildShapes() {
        setNeedsDisplay()
    }
    
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        super.draw(rect)
        
        guard let backgroundView else { return }
        
        let p = UIBezierPath()
        
        let fillColor = UIColor.red.withAlphaComponent(0.4)
        
        let strokeColor = UIColor.green.withAlphaComponent(1.0)
        let lineWidth = 10
        
        backgroundView.pages.forEach { page in
            let p1 = backgroundView.convert(point: CGPoint(x: page.size.width/3, y: page.size.height/3), from: page.index)
            let p2 = backgroundView.convert(point: CGPoint(x: page.size.width/3*2, y: page.size.height/3*2), from: page.index)
            let r: CGRect = .init(x: p1.x, y: p1.y, width: p2.x - p1.x, height: p2.y - p1.y)
            if r.intersects(rect) {
                p.append(.init(rect: r))
            }
        }
        
        fillColor.setFill()
        p.fill()
        strokeColor.setStroke()
        p.lineWidth = CGFloat(lineWidth)
        p.stroke()
    }
}
```

No need to add any layers.